# Is an eee-pc with an Atom N550 dual core OK for Rails 3 development?

Tags: eee-pc, ruby-on-rails

I'm buying an Asus eee-pc 1015PEM and hope to do test-driven Rails 3 development on it. Is the CPU fast enough or too painfully slow for this? I plan on installing Ubuntu.

I currently develop on a 11 inch Macbook Air 2010 model. It works fine as a Rails development machine. But for some reason I'm drawn to developing on a cheap little netbook.

I don't use any IDE's, and my development workflow is mostly switching between Vim, Gnu Screen, and bash.

Comment: I ran W7 with Aero on an Atom 230 single core 2gb ram for 9 months, it ran fine, I did more than surf and show PPT files, it was my main desktop PC. N550 is underestimated by those who have never owned/used one.

Comment: `I don't use any IDE's, and my development workflow is mostly switching between Vim, Gnu Screen, and bash.` - the Atom should be fine for this but I'm more concerned about what the cramped keyboard will do to your wrists

Comment: Is there some research or anecdotal evidence than a 90% size keyboard is bad for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that any EEE PC is not fast enough for development, sorry. I'd suggest buying a low-end laptop at the very least. You'll want a dual core with 2GB RAM at the very least!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing a netbook is good for is to surf web pages and show PowerPoint presentations. Everything else needs more power.